# Controlling downsize behaviour of ScrollPane within GridBagLayout

Tags: scala, swing, layout-manager, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I'm experimenting with manipulating images in a GUI. I need to have an image shown in a GUI, with several other components around it. If the GUI window is resized, only the image area needs to resize with it.

I thought using a `GridBagLayout` was the way to go, but when I do, the resize behaviour of the `ScrollPane` holding the image is unexpected: when the GUI window is downsized in a way that the available space is too small for the image in the `ScrollPane`, the `ScrollPane` component downsizes immediately to a dimension which is much smaller that the available space.

Image for code example: [qm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ljee.png)

```scala
import scala.swing.{ Button, GridBagPanel, Label, MainFrame, ScrollPane, SimpleSwingApplication }
import javax.swing.ImageIcon

object GridBag_vs_ScrollPane extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    def top = new MainFrame {
        title = "GridBag vs ScrollPane"
        contents = gui
    }

    val gui = new GridBagPanel {
        val fp_img = """.\resources\qm.png"""
        val scrPane = new ScrollPane( new Label { icon = new ImageIcon(fp_img) } )
        val button1 = new Button("Button 1")

        val c = new Constraints
        c.gridx = 0
        c.gridy = 0
        layout(button1) = c

        c.weighty = 1.0
        c.gridx = 0
        c.gridy = 1
        layout(scrPane) = c
    }
}
```

The behaviour of the `ScrollPane` I was looking for is more like the one of the next piece of code:

```scala
import javax.swing.ImageIcon

import scala.swing.{Label, MainFrame, ScrollPane, SimpleSwingApplication}

object SimpleScrollPane extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    def top = new MainFrame {
        title = "Simple ScrollPane"
        val fp_img = """.\resources\qm.png"""
        contents = new ScrollPane( new Label { icon = new ImageIcon(fp_img) } )
    }
}
```

I can’t figure how to get the desired behaviour, nor why the `ScrollPane` behaves differently in both GUI implementations.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Thank you, that (translated to scala: `c.fill = Fill.Both`) got me halfway to the solution (using all available vertical space). I also needed to add `c.weightx = 1.0`, to get the scroll pane to use the total width. I did play around with the `Fill` and the `weight` constraints, but apparently never in the correct combination.

Comment: How can I accept this as the correct answer?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - Answer added based upon your input. Now I just need to wait for 6 hours to accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion of  [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) got me halfway. I needed to add both`c.fill = Fill.Both` and `c.weightx = 1.0` to the constraints for the scroll pane.

The fact that the fill constraint is part of the solution is counter intuitive to me since the [tutorial on `GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) describes the fill constraints as «Used when the component's display area is larger than the component's requested size to determine whether and how to resize the component.», while in my case the requested size of the scroll pane component was actually larger than the available display area.

Answer (score 1):

In the component that you add to the scrollpane, override the

```
public Dimension getMinimumSize()
```

or

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
```

Different layout managers uses these values.